# passing text user input into another function as string

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have an tkinter entry field where user can input text in the GUI...

```
manager_name_entry = tkinter.Entry()
manager_name_entry.grid(in_=tab1, row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.N, pady=10)
manager_name_entry.focus_set()
```

I also have a function which gets this text...

```
def get_name(entry):
    name = entry.get()
    return name
```

And I have a button which calls a function called 'build_main'...

```
reports_btn1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Reports", width=12, height=0, command= build_main)
reports_btn1.grid(in_=tab1, row=1, column=1, sticky=tkinter.S, padx=0, pady=0)
```

Lastly I have a function called build_main which does some work.. I would like the user input to work by looking up a row from a Dataframe..

```
def build_main(name):
    df_manager = df_main[df_main['Employee'].str.contains(name)]
```

but for now, just to make sure it gets inside the `build_main` function I am just trying to...

```
print(name)
```

Why does the user entry not pass into the `build_main` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `command=` parameter on a `Button` determines which function to call, it won't pass any parameter. So the function you put there must be a function that doesn't have any argument.

The way to solve this is to fetch the user input from inside your function, instead of having it as a parameter:

```
def build_main():
    name = manager_name_entry.get()
    df_manager = df_main[df_main['Employee'].str.contains(name)]
```

Now that means the function must have a way to refer to the entry itself - usually we do that by making everything part of a class, so that you can store those objects that are useful in other functions as attributes of the class instance:

```
self.manager_name_entry = tkinter.Entry()
... then later ...

def build_main(self): # a method
    name = self.manager_name_entry.get()
    df_manager = df_main[df_main['Employee'].str.contains(name)]
```

Comment: Quick follow up. I am getting this error:

"NameError: name 'self' is not defined " on this line:

`self.manager_name_entry = tkinter.Entry()`

Comment: @DavidA to use that suggestion you have to refactor your code into a class, and use methods for everything - it is not just a *paste code* solution, it actually requires you to rethink a lot of things to make them fit in a object-oriented class approach.

Comment: I am seeing that in other posts.. I don't know about classes as I am only a week into coding with python but I will continue along my journey of learning. Thanks for your assistance!